# Best feasible Approach of implementing promises and sql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am building REST API's in node js in which I need to retreive some values from external api(bitgo api's) and then insert those data into mysql database . To achieve this I am using promises to asynchronusly call api's and after successful call insert data into mysql .For error handling I did apply `catch` block after last `then` . Below  is my code snippet . Is there any room for improvement in this code in terms of error handling or handling bulk request ? I am aiming this code for production use.

```
app.post('/registeruser',function(req,res){


var userid = 2;
var username = req.body.username;
var firstname = req.body.firstname;
var lastname = req.body.lastname;
var email = req.body.email;
var password = req.body.password;
var bitcoincashreceivingaddress; 
var bitcoinreceivingaddress ;
var litecoinreceivingaddress ;
var user_balance = 0;

bitcoincashaddress()
.then(function(response,resolve){
    bitcoincashreceivingaddress = response;
    return bitcoinaddress();
}).then(function(body2){

    bitcoinreceivingaddress = body2;
    return litecoinaddress();

}).then(function(body3){
    litecoinreceivingaddress = body3;

    connection.query("Insert into Usertable(userid,Username,firstname,lastname,emailaddress,password) values ('"+userid+"','"+username+"','"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','"+email+"','"+password+"')", function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('The result is: ', results);
            });


    connection.query("Insert into Wallettable(receivingaddress,user_balance,user_id,coinid) values ('"+bitcoinreceivingaddress+"',"+user_balance+",'"+userid+"','1')", function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('The result is: ', results);
            });
connection.end();



}).catch(function(err){
console.log(err);

});





function bitcoincashaddress (){
return new Promise (function (success, failure) { 
bitgo.coin('tbch').wallets().getWallet({ id: 'dumyaddress' })
.then(function(wallet) {
  return wallet.createAddress();
})
.then(function(newAddress) {
   var userbchaddress = newAddress.address;
   success(userbchaddress);

}).catch(function (err) {

       failure('Error in signup . Contact Admin');
    });
});

}

function bitcoinaddress (){
return new Promise (function (success, failure) { 
bitgo.coin('tbtc').wallets().getWallet({ id: 'dumyaddress' })
.then(function(wallet) {
  return wallet.createAddress();
})
.then(function(newAddress) {
   var userbtcaddress = newAddress.address;
   success(userbtcaddress);

}).catch(function (err) {

       failure('Error in creating bitcoincash address');
    });
});

}

function litecoinaddress (){
return new Promise (function (success, failure) { 
bitgo.coin('tltc').wallets().getWallet({ id: 'dumyaddress' })
.then(function(wallet) {
  return wallet.createAddress();
})
.then(function(newAddress) {
   var userltcaddress = newAddress.address;
   success(userltcaddress);

}).catch(function (err) {

       failure('Error in creating litecoin address');
    });
});

}
});
```

Comment: Promises, promises

Comment: yes any flaw you see in it ?